# Как сделать активацию аккаунта после регистрации по email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть интернет-магазин, почему то в woocommerce не приходят письма после регистрации чтобы активировать аккаунт. Видимо нету такой функции. Практический везде есть на интернет-магазинах. 
После регистрации просто приходит письмо, Добро пожаловать, и можно сразу зайти на сайт личного кабинета. А нужно сделать следующим образом: Чтобы когда покупатель на сайте проходил регистрацию, отправлялось письмо с ссылкой, только при переходе по ссылке аккаунт активировался. 
Регистрация будет только в личном кабинете. В оформление заказа не будет.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не знаю зачем такие хлопоты доставлять покупателям, но для обычной регистрации есть плагины. Наверно что-то есть и для WC.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал следующим образом. В бд добавляем 2 поля

```
`activate = 0`
и 
`act_link = saudnyi7nyxnehkunoq7qye2w` - ссылка,
```

которая будет генерироваться при регистрации.
Далее делаешь обработчик, что если пришел пользователь и логин совпадает со ссылкой которая в базе, то перезаписать 0 на 1 в поле `activate`.
Ну а после регистрации на почту отправлять ссылку на обработчик, который принимает логин и уникальный линк для активации.

Comment: Добавлю: чтобы не засорять базу, можно создать триггер, который с определённой периодичностью будет удалять учётные данные всех записей с `activate = 0` и датой регистрации не позднее той, что была, к примеру, месяц назад.

Comment: Не надо ничего никуда добавлять. В базе уже всё есть.

Comment: А есть ли плагин, который выполняет такую функцию ?